# Send erc20 Tokens using Alchemy

Tags: react-native, alchemyapi, alchemy

I am using the Alchemy SDK to build an ethereum wallet app on react native.  The docs (https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-send-transactions-on-ethereum) show me how to send Eth and I have already tested this and it works.  However, I don't see anywhere in the docs on how to specify which token should be sent.  I am wondering how I can set up my transaction object so that it will send the correct token.  Our app handles Eth and all erc20 tokens currently so that the user can see their balances.

Here is the method for sending Eth using Alchemy's SDK

```
const { Alchemy, Network, Wallet, Utils } = require("alchemy-sdk");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();
const { API_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

const settings = {
  apiKey: API_KEY,
  network: Network.ETH_GOERLI,
};
const alchemy = new Alchemy(settings);

let wallet = new Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY);

async function main() {
  const nonce = await alchemy.core.getTransactionCount(
    wallet.address,
    "latest"
  );

  let transaction = {
    to: "0xa238b6008Bc2FBd9E386A5d4784511980cE504Cd",
    value: Utils.parseEther("0.001"),
    gasLimit: "21000",
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: Utils.parseUnits("5", "gwei"),
    maxFeePerGas: Utils.parseUnits("20", "gwei"),
    nonce: nonce,
    type: 2,
    chainId: 5,
  };

  let rawTransaction = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
  let tx = await alchemy.core.sendTransaction(rawTransaction);
  console.log("Sent transaction", tx);
}

main();
```

I also found this article in the docs which explains the transaction object (https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/understanding-the-transaction-object-on-ethereum) but I still do not see where I would specify the token that I am sending.

Comment: Are you trying to make this as a REST endpoint, say a REST api Endpoint or something then calling it from your React native app?

Comment: This is just a utility function within my React Native project so no it's not a REST endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alchemy SDK does not contain any CORE methods that you can use to connect to an interface of a deployed ERC20 contract with a view to using it to send transactions. However, you can connect with a deployed instance of a contract using a library like `web3js` or `EthersJS`

To send tokens from an ERC20 contract, you need to use a library like `Ethersjs` to connect to an instance of the deployed contract. An `Ethereum` is also required to connect to a deployed instance of the contract. A Provider is an abstraction of a connection to the Ethereum network, providing a concise, consistent interface to standard Ethereum node functionality. With a Provider, you can connect to an instance of a deployed contract and carry out transactions, track events, etc.

To be able to send transactions with an ERC20 token using the Alchemy SDK, you need the following:

1. The deployed contract address.
2. The deployed contract ABI.
3. The Contract Provider.
4. EtherJS

To connect to the `EthersJS` provider, use your Alchemy API KEY.

**The following code is an example code which you can reference:**

```
const { Wallet, Utils } = require("alchemy-sdk");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();
const { ALCHEMY_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
const ethers = require("ethers");
const ABI = require("./ABI.json");

let wallet = new Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY);

const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x...";
const provider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider(
  `https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/${ALCHEMY_KEY}`
);

async function main() {
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, ABI, provider);
  const amount = Utils.parseEther("0.001");
  await contract.transfer(wallet.address, "<receiver-wallet-address>", amount);
  console.log("Sent ", amount);
}

main();
```